# Found Elasticsearch with Aliased Index with Routing

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

We have multiple organization having identical structure of records in Database. We are using ES with aliased index and routing features for each organization. Now, when we clear the ES index and start with clean state, then search records is coming properly from ES. But when we adding multiple organizations, ES is behaving strangely. Sometimes it is sending data of another organization or sometimes it just suppress data. Even more alarming, sometimes it is sending data of record which is not even searched ! "john" it is retuning "Ringo", searching via "Mick" returning "John".

Further Investigations :

1. Index only one org. Data is coming for that org.
2. Index another one org. Data is coming for that org too.
3. Index third org. Data is lost for first org !.

Images :

1. **Clean state :** https://imageshack.com/i/idNW3QVCp
2. **With one org. being indexed:**
3. **With another org. being indexed:**
4. **With third org. being index:**
5. **Log from Sf2:**

**Status of ES server :**

```json
{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 10,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "indices" : {
    "organizations" : {
      "index" : {
        "primary_size_in_bytes" : 54928,
        "size_in_bytes" : 54928
      },
      "translog" : {
        "operations" : 106
      },
      "docs" : {
        "num_docs" : 50,
        "max_doc" : 73,
        "deleted_docs" : 23
      },
      "merges" : {
        "current" : 0,
        "current_docs" : 0,
        "current_size_in_bytes" : 0,
        "total" : 0,
        "total_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "total_docs" : 0,
        "total_size_in_bytes" : 0
      },
      "refresh" : {
        "total" : 125,
        "total_time_in_millis" : 204
      },
      "flush" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "total_time_in_millis" : 0
      },
      "shards" : {
        "0" : [ {
          "routing" : {
            "state" : "STARTED",
            "primary" : true,
            "node" : "ficq9zDSRM2HJTGLk2BZ7g",
            "relocating_node" : null,
            "shard" : 0,
            "index" : "organizations"
          },
          "state" : "STARTED",
          "index" : {
            "size_in_bytes" : 15923
          },
          "translog" : {
            "id" : 1432033150513,
            "operations" : 42
          },
          "docs" : {
            "num_docs" : 21,
            "max_doc" : 21,
            "deleted_docs" : 0
          },
          "merges" : {
            "current" : 0,
            "current_docs" : 0,
            "current_size_in_bytes" : 0,
            "total" : 0,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 0,
            "total_docs" : 0,
            "total_size_in_bytes" : 0
          },
          "refresh" : {
            "total" : 25,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 114
          },
          "flush" : {
            "total" : 0,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 0
          }
        } ],
        "1" : [ {
          "routing" : {
            "state" : "STARTED",
            "primary" : true,
            "node" : "ficq9zDSRM2HJTGLk2BZ7g",
            "relocating_node" : null,
            "shard" : 1,
            "index" : "organizations"
          },
          "state" : "STARTED",
          "index" : {
            "size_in_bytes" : 123
          },
          "translog" : {
            "id" : 1432033150524,
            "operations" : 0
          },
          "docs" : {
            "num_docs" : 0,
            "max_doc" : 0,
            "deleted_docs" : 0
          },
          "merges" : {
            "current" : 0,
            "current_docs" : 0,
            "current_size_in_bytes" : 0,
            "total" : 0,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 0,
            "total_docs" : 0,
            "total_size_in_bytes" : 0
          },
          "refresh" : {
            "total" : 25,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 1
          },
          "flush" : {
            "total" : 0,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 0
          }
        } ],
        "2" : [ {
          "routing" : {
            "state" : "STARTED",
            "primary" : true,
            "node" : "ficq9zDSRM2HJTGLk2BZ7g",
            "relocating_node" : null,
            "shard" : 2,
            "index" : "organizations"
          },
          "state" : "STARTED",
          "index" : {
            "size_in_bytes" : 4782
          },
          "translog" : {
            "id" : 1432033150529,
            "operations" : 8
          },
          "docs" : {
            "num_docs" : 8,
            "max_doc" : 8,
            "deleted_docs" : 0
          },
          "merges" : {
            "current" : 0,
            "current_docs" : 0,
            "current_size_in_bytes" : 0,
            "total" : 0,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 0,
            "total_docs" : 0,
            "total_size_in_bytes" : 0
          },
          "refresh" : {
            "total" : 25,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 11
          },
          "flush" : {
            "total" : 0,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 0
          }
        } ],
        "3" : [ {
          "routing" : {
            "state" : "STARTED",
            "primary" : true,
            "node" : "ficq9zDSRM2HJTGLk2BZ7g",
            "relocating_node" : null,
            "shard" : 3,
            "index" : "organizations"
          },
          "state" : "STARTED",
          "index" : {
            "size_in_bytes" : 123
          },
          "translog" : {
            "id" : 1432033150518,
            "operations" : 0
          },
          "docs" : {
            "num_docs" : 0,
            "max_doc" : 0,
            "deleted_docs" : 0
          },
          "merges" : {
            "current" : 0,
            "current_docs" : 0,
            "current_size_in_bytes" : 0,
            "total" : 0,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 0,
            "total_docs" : 0,
            "total_size_in_bytes" : 0
          },
          "refresh" : {
            "total" : 25,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 0
          },
          "flush" : {
            "total" : 0,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 0
          }
        } ],
        "4" : [ {
          "routing" : {
            "state" : "STARTED",
            "primary" : true,
            "node" : "ficq9zDSRM2HJTGLk2BZ7g",
            "relocating_node" : null,
            "shard" : 4,
            "index" : "organizations"
          },
          "state" : "STARTED",
          "index" : {
            "size_in_bytes" : 33977
          },
          "translog" : {
            "id" : 1432033150546,
            "operations" : 56
          },
          "docs" : {
            "num_docs" : 21,
            "max_doc" : 44,
            "deleted_docs" : 23
          },
          "merges" : {
            "current" : 0,
            "current_docs" : 0,
            "current_size_in_bytes" : 0,
            "total" : 0,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 0,
            "total_docs" : 0,
            "total_size_in_bytes" : 0
          },
          "refresh" : {
            "total" : 25,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 78
          },
          "flush" : {
            "total" : 0,
            "total_time_in_millis" : 0
          }
        } ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It seems ES is overwriting data of existing aliases when another org. is being indexed. But that is deal breaker. **Please advice.**

Comment: Images :

    Clean state : https://imageshack.com/i/idNW3QVCp
    With one org. being indexed: https://imageshack.com/i/f0zTd4YEp , https://imageshack.com/i/idKl1oQrp
    With another org. being indexed:
    With third org. being index:
    Log from Sf2:

Comment: With another org. being indexed: https://imageshack.com/i/pbWP7YiNp, https://imageshack.com/i/p8eUMiDxp
With third org. being index: https://imageshack.com/i/ipxfEXo3p, https://imageshack.com/i/eyeS46fGp
Log from Sf2: https://imageshack.com/i/f03ZQ8IOp

Comment: What is the doc id you are sending while indexing. Aliases doesn't provide separation for the doc id. If you are providing same id for different org. It will override previous data. The id is like a unique key for your index irrespective of alias. Include sample data.

Comment: Hi Prabin,
Here is the sample data :
[2015-05-19 22:10:40] elastica.INFO: _bulk (PUT) 5.76 ms ["{\"index\":{\"_index\":\"thirdtry\",\"_type\":\"recipients\",\"_id\":1}}\n{\"id\":1,\"internalId\":null,\"firstName\":\"multi\",\"lastName\":\"packages\",\"email\":\"exam@test.com\",\"mailbox\":null,\"phoneNumber\":null,\"mobileNumber\":null,\"jointAccountHolder\":null,\"deliveryMode\":1,\"deleted\":null,\"address\":[]}\,"port":9200,"logger":"fos_elastica.logger","enabled":true}} []
[2015-05-19 22:10:40] elastica.INFO: thirdtry/_refresh (POST) 24.40 ms [] []

Comment: FosElasticaBundle is creating "_id" for every request and its value is always "1". But this overwriting of data happening for records which has similar values across organizations.